# H2 database fails to execute INSERT INTO table with composite primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, h2

I'm building a REST java application with spring boot 3.1.2 and maven. My idea was to use MySQL database in production, and switch to a in-memory H2 database while testing. I have successfully configured H2 in my **application.properties** file, by creating **application-test.properties** file that overrides datasource params while testing. I specified my **schema.sql** and **data.sql** files to create and populate my H2 database at start of testing:

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

**application-test.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:my_db;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.sql.init.mode=ALWAYS
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:/database/schema.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/database/data.sql
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE media (
  id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  release_date date NOT NULL,
  cover_image varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  description varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  audience_rating int NOT NULL,
  critic_rating int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT rating_domain CHECK (((audience_rating >= 0) and (audience_rating <= 100)))
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE person (
  id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  gender char(1) NOT NULL,
  profile_photo varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT const_person_gender CHECK ((gender in ('M','F','O')))
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE actor (
  person_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  is_star tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
  CONSTRAINT actor_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE acting (
  media_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  actor_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  is_starring tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (media_id,actor_id),
  CONSTRAINT acting_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT acting_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actor (person_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE acting_role (
  acting_media_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  acting_actor_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  name varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (acting_media_id,acting_actor_id,id),
  CONSTRAINT acting_role_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (acting_media_id) REFERENCES acting (media_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT acting_role_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (acting_actor_id) REFERENCES acting (actor_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The problem arose in my **data.sql** file while trying to populate acting table, which contains a composite primary key:

```
INSERT INTO acting(media_id,actor_id,is_starring) VALUES (1,2,1),(1,3,1);
```

Inserting *media*, *person* and *actor* works fine, only after inserting *acting* an exception is thrown:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "public.acting_role_ibfk_1_INDEX_A ON public.acting(media_id NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT) )
```

I'm guessing this is because H2 doesn't recognize my composite primary key in *acting* table, but rather treats them as double primary keys and only sees that I inserted the same *media_id* twice, throwing an exception. Or it could be because I'm inserting values in *acting* table first before *acting_role* table, which has a foreign key referencing *acting* table, so it throws an exception because I haven't yet inserted values in *acting_role* table, which have a value of NULL at that moment, even though it shouldn't do that.

Honestly I'm pretty lost here. I tried searching answers through the internet and AI, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Try without ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Comment: @Mar-Z I have tried your solution, but it still throws the same exception. I've switched to a MySQL test database now without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not answer about how to make the composite key work in H2, but a different way to accomplish a working system in both databases...

When I went to "database school" 30-odd years ago, I was taught that a primary key should be opaque - that is, have no "meaning".

That generally means not using a composite primary key, because if the keys are truly opaque, why would you need more than one?

So, keep your media_id and actor_id columns, and put a unique constraint on them, but don't use them as a primary key - add a single auto-incrementing primary key column instead.

Comment: Your comment about a workaround is very much appreciated! I was aware of your solution, but I designed it this way because a primary key is supposed to uniquely identify a row in a table, and acting rows identity is based on id of media and id of actor. Plus I didn't wish to burden my tables with unnecessary data. If no one else provides an answer, ill mark yours as the correct one.